# OpenLDAP password policy for a group

Tags: openldap, password-policy

Just wondering if OpenLDAP is able to assign a password policy to a specific group? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean by group, groupOfNames or similar the response is unfortunately **no**.

From:

```
man slapo-ppolicy
```

> **Every** account that should be subject to password policy control should
>   have a pwdPolicySubentry attribute containing the DN of a valid
>   pwdPolicy entry

Comment: According to this link: http://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-technical/201402/msg00317.html

You are correct!